# Giving Text coordinates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have drawn a bunch of rectangles using canvas, now i want text to **appear inside the boxes**.

I have all the coordinates of the boxes, is there any way i can give text coordinates so they appear in the box?

```
var Rad = 10
var Kolonne = 10
var Bredde = 350
var Høyde = 100
var Kolonnetall=0
var MellomromKolonne=100
var MellomromRad=25

    btnTegn.onclick=function(){

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(Kolonne,Rad,Bredde,Høyde)
  ctx.moveTo(Bredde/2+Kolonne,Rad)
  ctx.lineTo(Bredde/2+Kolonne,Rad+Høyde)
  ctx.stroke();
  Rad+=MellomromRad+Høyde
  Kolonnetall++

   if (Kolonnetall==5) {
    Rad=10
     Kolonne+=Bredde+MellomromKolonne
     Kolonnetall=0

 }
}
}
```

As you can see, i am making rectangels with a line in bewtween. I would like to be able to add text to them.

Comment: Please add some code...

Comment: I added some now! :)